# How to deploy and run Play! 2.1 to EC2 via Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, playframework-2.0, continuous-deployment

I have setup Jenkins for my Play! 2.1

I have setup Build and Deploy jobs, they work well. But I seem to cannot figure out how to deploy and run Play! from Jenkins to EC2.

For example, I used this command `play dist` to pack everything into a zip file in Build job and copy the artefact over to Deploy job. Then use `scp` to upload to EC2 via Publish-Over-SSH plugin, which works fine. Now, If I want Jenkins to run the App immediately, I will unzip the file and run `sh start` command. That would run the application run up but Play! wouldn't release the console so Jenkins job would never finish. So, how do I run Play! 2.1 and release the console so Jenkins can finish the job and how do I kill the old application if a new commit has come in? So, the process will keep going.

Comment: That is one big question you ask there. And there are so many answers possible. Be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `nohup` command combined with the `&` char.

```
nohup ./start.sh &
```

That should run the process on background and not kill the application when you logout.

**NB** : You might have to install `nohup`.